# how to alias class name in css or sass

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

Can I create an alias to a css class?

I am using this font-awesome and I am trying to create an alias name for some of the icon classes. So that `.icon-globe` will also called `.globe`.

How can I accomplish such thing?

Answer (score 27):

There's no such thing as aliasing.  Sass does have the `@extend` directive, but the solution isn't entirely obvious until you look into the source.

Source: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/sass/font-awesome.scss

```
[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

// snip

.icon-globe:before                { content: "\f0ac"; }
```

Even if you made `.globe` extend `.icon-globe`, you'll be missing out on most of what makes the FontAwesome styles because of how they built the selector.  You have to extend the other selector as well.

This:

```
.globe {
    @extend .icon-globe;
    @extend [class^="icon-"];
}
```

compiles to

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, .globe:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit; }

.icon-globe:before, .globe:before {
  content: "\f0ac"; }
```

Note that the `icon-` prefix was deliberate.  You get smaller CSS files this way, rather than attaching all of those styles to all ~200 classes that come with FontAwesome.  You *can* do it, but I don't think the result is very good.

Answer (score 26):

Easiest way I can think of is to use javascript/jquery.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.globe').addClass('icon-globe');
});
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted my answer, please leave a comment if you feel that the code is inadequate, or edit my answer and I'll be happy to review your request :)

Comment: Old Question ...though , but it is clear that the caller is not asking this. What they want to know is how they can start using .globe , instead of using .icon-globe.

Comment: @mehaase and apparently 13 people found that answer to be helpful, and 7 disliked it SO much they felt they needed to downvote it. I think I'll keep it

Comment: You asked for a comment about the downvote, so I left one. No need to get defensive.

Comment: late reply, I know, but.... @mehaase The question is not about CSS or SASS; the OP wants to know how to accomplish a certain task, namely use `.globe` in his CSS instead of `.icon-globe`. It seems clear that he thinks the answer should be a CSS/SASS answer, but he may not know about other options, such as jQuery. You cannot ask about something you don't know about.

OneChillDude's response accomplishes exactly what bymannan asked. @Scalable

Comment: Answers from people like OneChillDude that demonstrate an ability to recognize the root problem a quesiton is asking about and help solve that (as opposed to "you can't do exactly what you asked about") is precisely why we come to SO.

Comment: For me, this answer feels like this: `How can I change my REST endpoint to return a different object?` and then the response `Use jQuery to change that stuff on the UI`. - OP did not mention jQuery in their post. I was looking for a way to structure SCSS better with silly long class names that would hurt readability. So I disagree with @jpwynn , my root problem is different and I don't even have jQuery in my project.

Comment: it would be nice to have a translation to vanilla JS

Answer (score 18):

> I know this is an older question but I am answering this because the thread looks incomplete...

You can easily do this with `SASS` by extending the `icon-globe` class

```
.globe{
    @extend .icon-globe !optional;
}
```

The output CSS will be as,

```
.globe,.icon-globe{
   /* CSS Properties */
}
```

Considering the new class names of Font-Awesome, you will be need to using the `.fa-globe` with multiple class extending

```
.globe{
    @extend .fa, .fa-globe !optional;
}
```

The output CSS will be as,

```
.fa,.globe{
 /* ... */
}

.globe,.fa-globe{
   /* CSS Properties */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use SASS mixin `@content` to create an alias for a selector or combination of them like this:

```
@mixin icon {
   .icon-globe,
   .globe {
      @content;
   }
}

@include icon {
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

SASS will generate this for you:

```css
.icon-globe,
.globe {
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

Read more about [SASS mixin content block](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#content-blocks);

Comment: This is a much saner response for 2019 than using jQuery

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the same styles to several classes using plain css comma separated selectors:

```
.icon-globe, .globe {
  //styles
}
```

Will apply the same styles to `<i class="icon-globe">` and `<i class="globe">`.

Comment: Thanks. Will only work if I define the styles in this block? The thing is, don't want to modify the font-awesome file.

Comment: Yes also, in some case, I may not have 'access' to the class like or may not want to invest energy to find where it is defined.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [CSS Crush](http://the-echoplex.net/csscrush/) which allows you to create aliases http://the-echoplex.net/csscrush/#core--selector-aliases

**Usage**

```
@selector globe :any( .icon-globe, .globe );

:globe {
  color: red;
}
```

**Outputs**

```
.icon-globe, .globe {
  color: red;
}
```