# Apply pseudo class styling to all preceding classes

Tags: html, css

So if I am applying a styling such as:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3 {}
```

What is a way I can then apply to specific pseudo styles of those classes in the same line without repeating all the class names?

Comment: Have you considered a CSS preprocessor such as LESS or SASS? They offer nesting. It sounds like that's what you're wanting.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/13335575/4759033

Comment: If the classes are going to have same styles and pseudo-classes then would it not be a better idea to make them into a single class?

Comment: The intent is to integrate SASS in next iteration, but yeah, that will kind of do the trick. For now though, it won't.

Comment: @Harry - no, not necessarily as the base classes do differ and the names aren't necessarily that simple.

Comment: @SatejS - thanks for that Satej, but that won't work quite like I am after.

Comment: @Mark: The base classes can differ but you can still attach a common class to it because an element can have as many classes as needed. Anyway, its upto you.

Comment: @Harry - ah yes, I already do that, but didn't think of it that way. Problem there now is that I have to go through and find all them elements with those classes and then add that class. My thought was to simply add/modify the css for brevity for now.

Comment: @Mark: I understand mate. I was just trying to see if you've already thought about that. At present there is no pure CSS way of doing this but I think there is a selector in CSS4.

Answer (score 1):

I am sometimes using stylus , stylus is a CSS precompiler.For your case I will give you an example how it will look in stylus.

```
.class1 , .class2 , .class3
  color red
  background-color blue 
     &:hover 
          color blue
          background-color red
```

this code above will automatically precompile the code into your .css file like this

```
.class1,
.class2,
.class3 {
  color: #f00;
  background-color: #00f;
}
.class1:hover,
.class2:hover,
.class3:hover {
  color: #00f;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

If you run for SASS/LESS it will look almost the same , but with scopes.