# Aliasing font-awesome icons

Tags: font-awesome

font-awesome V 5.6.3

Is there a simple way to create your own aliases for font-awesome icons?

For example, I use 'fa-city' to represent an organisation throughout my application, but would rather use my own 'fa-myicon-organisation' (or something similar), an alias for fa-city.  That way if ever I decided to use a different icon for organisations, I would only need to change it in one place.

Comment: You have few options, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335544/how-to-alias-class-name-in-css-or-sass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to alias class name in css or sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335544/how-to-alias-class-name-in-css-or-sass)